# rate command with discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I wanna know how can I make the rate stable so the numbers won't change every time when I tag someone or doing it by myself.

```
client.on('message', message =>{
  if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + "rate")) {
    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#B99DF0')
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    if (!args[1]){
    newEmbed.setDescription(`**${message.author.tag} I would rate you a `+number+`/100**`)
    } else {
      let user = message.mentions.users.first();
      if (!user){
        return newEmbed.setDescription('please include who you are rating.')
      }
      newEmbed.setDescription(`**${message.author.tag} I would rate `+user.username+` a `+number+`/100**`)
    }
message.channel.send(newEmbed)
  }
})
```

Comment: Some guy told me to make it in a database, but I have no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about having the rating stay constant for specific users, you'll need to use a database of some sort, otherwise you'll have no possible way to do so.

A good database to start off with would be [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/). If that doesn't work out for you, try [out this article on the discord.js tutorial](https://discordjs.guide/sequelize/#a-simple-tag-system).

Take your time to learn the basics of a database, don't rush it for the simplicity of the command. After you get comfortable with databases, you'll know exactly how to do it